# Notepad++ можно ли сделать так, чтобы пробелы ставились не для абзаца, а для строки?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ можно ли сделать так, чтобы пробелы ставились не для абзаца, а для строки? Я хочу, чтобы это было, как, например, в WordPad. Прикладываю скриншот.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю нельзя. Но самое главное, зачем? Вы же понимаете, что на самом деле это у вас (в нотепаде) одна длинная строка, которая отображается как несколько только из-за включенного автопереноса? Таб перед каждой строчкой - это просто красивость автопереноса, в файл эти табы не сохраняются.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat о, ты вроде разбираешься в npp, раз ответил. слушай, а я вот открываю npp, и уменя открывается старая вкладка. это здорово, что история сохраняется. но можно ли сделать так, чтобы при открытии npp автоматически открывалась еще и новая вкладка? чтобы я мог сразу писать что-то в чистую вкладку, а не создавать специально еще одну.

Comment: Я ничего такого в настройках не вижу.

Comment: _но можно ли сделать так, чтобы при открытии npp автоматически открывалась еще и новая вкладка?_ А что, так трудно Ctrl+N нажать или дважды щелкнуть на свободном месте?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение моей проблемы.
Settings -> Preferences -> Editing - Line wrap - Default.